# Cannot connect to server.local from unix-based Machine

Tags: networking, unix, dns, windows-server-2008-r2, iis

I'm running an internal Website that our Employees can access using the address `http://server.local`. The server is running IIS 7 and the Clients are Windows 7 and 10. It all works fine.

However, when I try to access the website from a unixbased machine, using the .local url, I'm unable to connect but I get a connection to the server using its IP address.

Ping to server.local fails while ping to its IP succeeds.

ifconfig result:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:3b:70:7c  
      inet addr:192.168.0.15  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::b2c9:2a0f:2d75:2d97/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:14715 errors:0 dropped:1696 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6207 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:996272 (972.9 KiB)  TX bytes:2436155 (2.3 MiB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:162 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:162 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:34359 (33.5 KiB)  TX bytes:34359 (33.5 KiB)
```

Also, DNS Server IP and Search Domain is shown correctly on my Mac (using automatic DHCP Ethernet Connection).

I'm happy for any hint that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What happens if you try to `nslookup` (or the equivalent) `server.local` on that machine?

Comment: nslookup result: Server: 192.168.0.1 / Address: 192.168.0.1#53 ** server can't find server.local: NXDOMAIN

Comment: So likely your DNS server doesn't have an entry for `server.local`. In addition I'd expect it to be `server.domain.local`. Did you verify whenever you get an answer from the DNS server on one of the "working" clients? Did you check your DNS server configuration?

Comment: In the DNS server I have an A record for server (Host: server, FQDN server.domain.local, IP 192.168.0.1) - I tried to ping to server using FQDN and that works - so should I just switch to server.domain.local entirely?

Comment: In that case `server.local` shouldn't really work on the other computers as well. `http://server` might though as they might automatically suffix the domain or find the server using NetBIOS or similar. It would depend on your judgement what you do. You might also just use the full name on the Mac or change it's configuration.